# dhcpcd listening on port 68

Tags: linux, dhcpcd

I'm using dhcpcd to statically set the interface addresses. However, dhcpcd always listens on port 68, even if setting the interfaces as static addresses. It's probably strange to have a dhcp client that doesn't listen to bootp, but how do i stop dhcpcd from binding to an interface?

Comment: This is not making sense to me. You are using a DHCP server, you are talking about port numbers in relation to "static addresses" (which is not a relation AFAIK) and then you are talking about a DHCP client that "listens" to bootp? Can you tell us what you're actually trying to achieve or solve here?

Comment: dhcpd is a dhcp server. dhcpcd is a dhcp client. It comes as the standard method of setting ip addresses and interfaces for some distributions instead of the usual networking service. As a client, it listens for bootp configuration on port 68. It also is able to set static addresses. The question is, can this be configured to not listen on the port if it is just setting static addresses?

Comment: Mentioning your Linux distribution would be important here. I think Raspbian has tried to consolidate all network interface configuration to `dhcpcd`, even for static IP addresses. But this is far from universal solution, and on most other distributions, you can easily configure static addresses so that `dhcpcd` needs not run at all.

Comment: Either use a dhcp client to get dynamic addresses, or set a static address through some other means. Don't use a dhcp client to set statis addresses, that's just wrong.

Comment: oh yes i do agree, so i've switched dhcpcd off. But, in the attempt of trying to fit into the mindset of the distro creators, is it possible to use dhcpcd but not have it bind to any interfaces.

Comment: Throughout our environment, we use DHCP to set an IP allocated to devices, and that IP never changes.  Its pretty common to do that in places that use PXE netboot.  So it's perfectly fine to use dhcpcd even in situations where the IP is static.

dhcpcd has to bind to the interface on port 68 for it to get broadcast messages from the DHCP server.  That's how the protocol works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dhcpcd expects you to add routes. So setting static interface addresses doesn't stop it from being prepared for actual DHCP work.

Explicitly rejecting BOOTP (through 'require dhcp_message_type') also doesn't stop it from binding to 68...

According to the [source code](https://github.com/NetworkConfiguration/dhcpcd/blob/29f6c47b9e1eac058eee71116e6aa1038e8fef7e/src/dhcp.c), binding to 68 is necessary "so that the kernel never sends an ICMP port unreachable message back to the DHCP server."